# Combine two Docker files for multi-stage build containing nginx and php

Tags: php, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I need to deploy a PHP application (including source) as a single docker image.

During development, I used docker-compose to setup two docker images: One is derived from nginx, one is from php-fpm.

I was hoping that I can just combine the original dockerfile definitions into one single dockerfile in order to get a single docker image for deployment. I would imagine something like this for the (minimal example) dockerfile:

```
# Install PHP-FPM
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:8.1-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql # do some installations

# Install nginx
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nginx
ADD src/public /usr/share/nginx/html/public # the directory public contains index.html and index.php
ADD conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf # see below
```

The nginx config file looks something like this:

```
server {

    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
```

I was able to build and run this new dockerfile, but the PHP part seems to be ignored. The resulting image is able to serve html files and the PHP files are just downloaded. Obviously, the PHP setup is not working, but I cannot figure out what I am missing.

I read that I somehow need to "copy" the first build into the second build part. However, I am not sure what that would be.

How can I adjust the Dockerfile above to make PHP work as well?

Comment: The Nginx build stage doesn't include a PHP interpreter.  If you can't make the application serve its own static assets, you really do need two separate containers here, one for the Nginx proxy and one for the PHP-FPM server, and those should properly be two separate images.